# Is it useful to have multiple copies of a monster?

Tags: monster-sanctuary

I hatched a Blob in the first area of Monster Sanctuary! Then I kept fighting blobs, and kept hatching more eggs. Now I have more Blobs than I know what to do with -- literally!

Are the second and further copies useful? Is there any variance between two monsters of the same type? Or should I just find a way to dump the duplicate eggs?